# TextBox's enable disable using knockout observable dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to run a loop on div having three controls of type text-boxes .

I built a sample fiddle which  explain basic structure `:` http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/60/

I have to work out something where i have to enable/disable text boxes based on status .

**Case 1 :** if i have status value of 1 or 2 entire row should be disabled i.e all 3 text boxes should be disabled

**Case 2 :** If i have status value of 3 i need 1st text-box and last text box disabled leaving 2nd text-box  editable

**Case 3 :** if it has any other status value other than what i mentioned above i just need to make it editable all of them .

Well i have to make use of some binding attribute to achieve this i tried using

`attr:{disable:true}` or `attr:{disable:false}` but this wont help me i have to do something unconventional if/else .

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with sub-viewmodels that determine the state of each checkbox with a `ko.computed`. This provides maximum code clarity in both the view and the view model.

```
function PhoneNumberViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.code = ko.observable(data.Code);
    self.date = ko.observable(data.Date);
    self.status = ko.observable(data.status);
    self.disableCode = ko.computed(function () {
        var s = self.status();
        return s === "1" || s === "2"  || s === "3";
    });
    self.disableDate = ko.computed(function () {
        var s = self.status();
        return s === "1" || s === "2";
    });
    self.disableStatus = ko.computed(function () {
        var s = self.status();
        return s === "1" || s === "2"  || s === "3";
    });
}
PhoneNumberViewModel.create = function (data) {
    return new PhoneNumberViewModel(data);
};
function PhoneViewModel(phoneNumbers) {
    var self = this;
    self.phoneList = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(phoneNumbers, PhoneNumberViewModel.create)
    );
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
ko.applyBindings(new PhoneViewModel([
    {Code: "123", Date: "12/12", status: "1"},
    {Code: "345", Date: "10/12", status: "2"},
    {Code: "567", Date: "7/7", status: "3"},
    {Code: "789", Date: "4/9", status: "4"}
]));
```

and

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: phoneList">
    <label>Country Code:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value: code, disable: disableCode" />
    <label>Date:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value: date, disable: disableDate" />
    <label>Status:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value: status, disable: disableStatus" />
    <br />
</div>
```

Notes:

- The overwhelmingly accepted convention in JavaScript is to `PascalCase` *only* object constructors and to `camelCase` everything else. Consider writing your code that way as well.
- You might want to look into the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which can help you map your raw data to, in this case, `PhoneNumberViewModel`.
- Making the `Status` field's "disabled" state dependent on its own value is not the smartest thing to do, from a UX perspective.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/63/

Comment: knowledgeable answer . glad you bought some interesting things up . very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enable` binding with arbitrary statements to determine whether to enable or disable input fields.

For example, in your case you would change

`<input type="text"  data-bind="value:Code" />`

to

`<input type="text"  data-bind="value:Code, enable:status == 1 || status == 2" />`

In the case that `status` is either 1 or 2, the input field for `Code` will be disabled; otherwise, it allows input.

[This edit of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/62/) includes simple usage of the `enable` binding, which is [explained officially](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) in the Knockout documentation.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with links to external resources alone. Link rot may make your answer useless in the future, unless you include the relevant code in your answer directly.